# Inserting and displaying a lot of items using Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using listBox to  show a lot of items (number of items>1000000). But it can show only the items which are in integer range. I have searched a lot, but I found nothing.
I want to know if there is any way to make listBox show items in "long" range?

Comment: Well, if the capacity of the ListBox is only measured by an int, then you can't add more than int.MaxValue items. Do you really want to add > 1m items to a listbox? Can you not use a search textbox in combination with the listbox to narrow down the selection candidates?

Comment: I have done it before. But It is a school project and the user must be able to view his/her contents which are listed and "number of contents are > 1m" !!

Comment: In this scenario, I think your only option is paging or limiting the number of rows you return via filtering or grouping.

Comment: Paging is a way. Thank U.